How to extract outline of a grid-like plot when you have information about the lines?
I am trying to get the outline of a plot that looks like this:

As you can see I have information about not only the points but the lines so I basically want to have all the inner lines removed.
I tried alpha hull but its not perfect at the sharp turns. Also, it doesn't use the line information that I have. Here is the outline I obtained using alpha hull:

I also tried forming a graph, but couldn't exactly decide a criteria to decide if the node is an outline node or not.
So, is there a way to get the outline of this object?

Start by identifying a directed edge you know is on the outline. For instance, find the vertex with the lowest X-coordinate (breaking ties by Y coordinate), then find the directed edge which starts at that vertex and has the lowest (signed) slope. That's your first "current" edge.
Mark the current directed edge as being part of the outline. Then find the directed edge which starts at the current edge's end vertex and makes the lowest (signed) angle with the current edge. So if possible you want to turn right, relative to the current edge; if not, you want to go straight; if that's not possible either, you want to turn left.
Eventually you will get back to the first edge, and then you know the outline is complete.

I think one approach would be to:

Construct many small polygons from the edges provided (enough to cover the whole of the shape at least once)
Use "polygon boolean operations" to combine all the overlapping polygons into one large polygon (there are well established libraries for this, eg clipper/CGAL)
Interpret the points of the combined polygon as the outline.


It seems like graph theory applies here.

Consider each point a vertex, and each line can be split up into line segments (if it isn't already), which can be used to construct a graph that shows the connections between each point. How easy this is depends on what your data looks like.
Find one of the four extreme points is via (x,y) sort. See Andrew's algorithm for convex hulls as an example. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain
Extreme points should only have two connected points. From here, you can use the gift-wrapping algorithm to work your way around the perimeter. It's much more efficent though as using the graph, as it only considers the 2-4 neighboring points for each point rather than all points not on the hull. This limitation also prevents it from turning into a convex or alpha hull. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Performance is O(N) in terms of the number of points as long as you don't actually sort the points when looking for the first extreme point instead of just finding the min or max.
Edit: Looks like this is a more detailed version of Sneftel's answer.
